# Is there a good way to create general property name can support multi properties?

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net, jsonconvert

I need to create a data class which used for JsonConvert. Most of the resource string which used to be converted are same except the following properties:

```
public class DataType
{
        public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Create_Date { get; set; }
}
```

Because in the resource string there are 2 types :
"create_date": "2021-01-15T18:43:13.061+0000",
&
"createdate": "2021-01-15T18:43:13.061+0000",

with the following JsonConvert:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataType>(resourceStr);
```

The output of one of the datetime property will be wrong value. Is there a good way to use one property to handle both of these two formats?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with [MCVE] including inline JSON value as constant in the code. Very unclear what exactly does not work and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved by add another private property with alter name. Then the class will support to convert both CreateDate and Create_Date with a single display name;

```
public DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("Create_Date")]
        private DateTimeOffset CreateDate2
        {
            set => CreateDate = value;
        }
```